# JSF 2.0: ajax request when press ENTER

Tags: ajax, jsf

i need to do an ajax request when i click "enter" in inputText field, without refresh page.
That's my code:

```
<h:form id="form-test">
   <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
   <p:inputText id="inputEnter" 
             onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false; }" 
             value="#{bean.content}">
       <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.save}" update="messages"/>
   </p:inputText>
</h:form>
```

And in bean I have a simple method:

```
public void save(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
  ...
}
```

All works, but It refresh page !!! Why ? How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a thread with a question somehow like yours [How to handle the ENTER keypressed to trigger an onBlur() event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548176/how-to-handle-the-enter-keypressed-to-trigger-an-onblur-event)

I would just change

```
onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {e.preventDefault();
inputEnter.onchange(); return false; }"
```

If you use JQuery

```
$('#form-test\\:inputEnter').onchange();
```

Comment: solved my problem. I needed to remove an event from dataTable's filter on "enter clic". this is my code
`onkeydown="PF('organicGroupsTable').filter(); return !(event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13);"`
Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to enter the render param , so it does not render the whole page again.

```
<h:form id="form-test">
   <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
   <p:inputText id="inputEnter" 
             onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false; }" 
             value="#{bean.content}">
       <f:ajax event="change" render="messages" listener="#{bean.save}" update="messages"/>
   </p:inputText>
</h:form>
```